# 1 is gcd(x,y) but 1 cannot be expressed as ax+by where a,b,x,y are in Z[sqrt(-5)].

Tags: ring-theory

I am working in the ring Z[sqrt(-5)]. I have shown that 1 is a gcd(x, y) where x=3 and y=2+sqrt(-5). I would like to show however that 1 cannot be expressed as ax+by where a, b are in Z[sqrt(-5)]. I have tried letting a and b be arbitrary elements of the ring and rearranging ax+by=1 to try to find a contradiction but this has not worked. Can anybody help?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider integers $m,n,p,q$ such that
$$a=m+n\sqrt{-5}$$
$$b=p+q\sqrt{-5}$$

Then $3m+3n\sqrt{-5}+2p-5q+\sqrt{-5}(p+2q)=1$. That is:
$$3m+2p-5q=1$$
and
$$3n+p+2q=0$$
Now, solve for $p$ in  the latter equation and substitute in the former to get
$$3m-6n-4q-5q=1$$
Is that possible?